# Subclassing Python dictionary to override __setitem__

Tags: python, dictionary, subclass

I am building a class which subclasses `dict`, and overrides `__setitem__`. I would like to be certain that my method will be called in all instances where dictionary items could possibly be set.

I have discovered three situations where Python (in this case, 2.6.4) does not call my overridden `__setitem__` method when setting values, and instead calls `PyDict_SetItem` directly

1. In the constructor
2. In the `setdefault` method
3. In the `update` method

As a very simple test:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print "Here"
        super(MyDict, self).__setitem__(key, str(value).upper())

>>> a = MyDict(abc=123)
>>> a['def'] = 234
Here
>>> a.update({'ghi': 345})
>>> a.setdefault('jkl', 456)
456
>>> print a
{'jkl': 456, 'abc': 123, 'ghi': 345, 'def': '234'}
```

You can see that the overridden method is only called when setting the items explicitly. To get Python to always call my `__setitem__` method, I have had to reimplement those three methods, like this:

```
class MyUpdateDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print "Here"
        super(MyUpdateDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args:
            if len(args) > 1:
                raise TypeError("update expected at most 1 arguments, got %d" % len(args))
            other = dict(args[0])
            for key in other:
                self[key] = other[key]
        for key in kwargs:
            self[key] = kwargs[key]

    def setdefault(self, key, value=None):
        if key not in self:
            self[key] = value
        return self[key]
```

Are there any other methods which I need to override, in order to know that Python will *always* call my `__setitem__` method?

**UPDATE**

Per gs's suggestion, I've tried subclassing UserDict (actually, IterableUserDict, since I want to iterate over the keys) like this:

```
from UserDict import *;
class MyUserDict(IterableUserDict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        UserDict.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print "Here"
        UserDict.__setitem__(self,key, value)
```

This class seems to correctly call my `__setitem__` on `setdefault`, but it doesn't call it on `update`, or when initial data is provided to the constructor.

**UPDATE 2**

Peter Hansen's suggestion got me to look more carefully at dictobject.c, and I realised that the update method could be simplified a bit, since the built-in dictionary constructor simply calls the built-in update method anyway. It now looks like this:

```
def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if len(args) > 1:
        raise TypeError("update expected at most 1 arguments, got %d" % len(args))
    other = dict(*args, **kwargs)
    for key in other:
        self[key] = other[key]
```

Comment: Does it work if you subclass UserDict instead of the normal dict?

Comment: I honestly didn't realise that UserDict was still around :) I'll try it

Comment: Userdict would have been nice, but unfortunately, its update method simply calls update on the underlying data dictionary.

Comment: When you re-implement update(), be sure to check `help(dict.update)` for details of what it actually does.  I just went through this myself... your version is not an equivalent reimplementation.

Comment: @Peter: My reasoning was that since dict's constructor essentially calls update(), then calling dict(args[0]) should do exactly what is required/expected by update. Can you see a situation where I would get different behaviour from a built-in dict?

Comment: Doesn't seem to handle nested dicts (where presumably, you would want them to be created with your subclassed dicts).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, since I eventually decided that I really *do* want to subclass Dict, rather than creating a new mapping class, and UserDict still defers to the underlying Dict object in some cases, rather than using the provided `__setitem__`.

After reading and re-reading the Python 2.6.4 source (mostly `Objects/dictobject.c`, but I grepped eveywhere else to see where the various methods are used,) my understanding is that the following code *is* sufficient to have my __setitem__ called every time that the object is changed, and to otherwise behave exactly as a Python Dict:

Peter Hansen's suggestion got me to look more carefully at `dictobject.c`, and I realised that the update method in my original answer could be simplified a bit, since the built-in dictionary constructor simply calls the built-in update method anyway. So the second update in my answer has been added to the code below (by some helpful person ;-).

```
class MyUpdateDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        # optional processing here
        super(MyUpdateDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args:
            if len(args) > 1:
                raise TypeError("update expected at most 1 arguments, "
                                "got %d" % len(args))
            other = dict(args[0])
            for key in other:
                self[key] = other[key]
        for key in kwargs:
            self[key] = kwargs[key]

    def setdefault(self, key, value=None):
        if key not in self:
            self[key] = value
        return self[key]
```

I've tested it with this code:

```
def test_updates(dictish):
    dictish['abc'] = 123
    dictish.update({'def': 234})
    dictish.update(red=1, blue=2)
    dictish.update([('orange', 3), ('green',4)])
    dictish.update({'hello': 'kitty'}, black='white')
    dictish.update({'yellow': 5}, yellow=6)
    dictish.setdefault('brown',7)
    dictish.setdefault('pink')
    try:
        dictish.update({'gold': 8}, [('purple', 9)], silver=10)
    except TypeError:
        pass
    else:
        raise RunTimeException("Error did not occur as planned")

python_dict = dict([('b',2),('c',3)],a=1)
test_updates(python_dict)

my_dict = MyUpdateDict([('b',2),('c',3)],a=1)
test_updates(my_dict)
```

and it passes. All other implementations I've tried have failed at some point. I'll still accept any answers that show me that I've missed something, but otherwise, I'm ticking the checkmark beside this one in a couple of days, and calling it the right answer :)

Comment: If I understand what you describe in UPDATE 2 of your question, I think you should also update the code in this answer of yours that you accepted.

Comment: Although your code for testing isn't very rigorous, in that it doesn't even check to see if your dict subclass methods are being called when it's passed a `MyUpdateDict` instance, my own version of it that checks that indicates it does, so my up-vote stands.

Comment: have you per chance investigated this for `defaultdict` and/or more recent versions of python (2.7 in particular)?

Comment: @Ian Clelland: An excellent question and answer. In addition to being interesting and quite edifying overall, I also found it very helpful in a particular problem I've been facing. Cheers!

Comment: @drevicko It seems a subclass of defaultdict will override `__setitem__` for the purpose of setting values to defaults. I need a way to circumvent this, though, as I want to disallow directly setting items on the subclass...

Comment: PS: It turned out subclassing `dict` and overriding both `__missing__`, `get` and the explicitly mutating methods (`pop`, `popitem`, `update`, `clear`) and dunder methods (`__delitem__`) was easier than making a `defaultdict` work. (All my reported results here are with python 3.)

Answer (score 4):

What is your use-case for subclassing dict?

You don't need to do this to implement a dict-like object, and it might be simpler in your case to write an ordinary class, then add support for the required subset of the dict interface.

The best way to accomplish what you're after is probably the MutableMapping abstract base class. [PEP 3119 -- Introducing Abstract Base Classes](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/)

This will also help you anser the question "Are there any other methods which I need to override?". You will need to override all the abstract methods. For MutableMapping: Abstract methods include **setitem**, **delitem**. Concrete methods include pop, popitem, clear, update.

Comment: I'm overriding setitem in order to do some data validation. The object is essentially a dictionary with some extra methods that act on its data, and I'd like the coders using it to be able to use it exactly as they would use a dictionary, without a long list of methods to stay away from. I'll take a look at ABCs; If they work, then I will have to see if I can upgrade all of the deployment environments to 2.6

Answer (score 4):

I found Ian answer and comments very helpful and clear. I would just point out that maybe a first call to the super-class `__init__` method might be safer, when not necessary: I  recently needed to implement a custom [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) (I'm working with Python 2.7): after implementing and modifying my code according to the proposed `MyUpdateDict` implementation, I found out that by simply replacing

```
class MyUpdateDict(dict):
```

with:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
class MyUpdateDict(OrderedDict):
```

then the test code posted above failed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Desktop/test_updates.py", line 52, in <module>
    my_dict = MyUpdateDict([('b',2),('c',3)],a=1)
File "Desktop/test_updates.py", line 5, in __init__
    self.update(*args, **kwargs)
File "Desktop/test_updates.py", line 18, in update
    self[key] = other[key]
File "Desktop/test_updates.py", line 9, in __setitem__
    super(MyUpdateDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 59, in __setitem__
    root = self.__root
AttributeError: 'MyUpdateDict' object has no attribute '_OrderedDict__root'
```

Looking at [collections.py code](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/collections.py) it turns out that OrderedDict *needs* its `__init__` method to be called in order to initialize and setup necessary custom attributes.

Therefore, by simply adding a first call to the super `__init__` method,

```
from collections import OrderedDict
class MyUpdateDict(Orderedict):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyUpdateDict, self).__init__() #<-- HERE call to super __init__
    self.update(*args, **kwargs)
```

we have a more general solution which apparently works for both dict and  OrderedDict.

I cannot state if this solution is generally valid, because I tested it with OrderedDict only. However, it is likely that a call to the super `__init__` method is either harmless or necessary rather than harmful, when trying to extend other dict subclasses

Answer (score 0):

Use object.keyname = value instead of object["keyname"] = value

Comment: While you *could* do this to save a key-value pair... it doesn't help in fixing the issue and this question doesn't require a workaround (based on the accepted answer...)