# Creating a Python dict and omitting items if the value is None

Tags: python, dictionary

I'll describe the motivation below, but the essential question: I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
# THIS DOESN'T WORK
def foo(var1, var2):
    d = {
        'a': var1,
        'b': var2 if var2 is not None,  # SyntaxError
    }
    return d

>>> foo(3, 4)
{'a': 3, 'b': 4}
>>> foo(3, None)
{'a': 3}
```

This description doesn't work because you're not allowed to have dict `(key, value)` pairs without a value. You have to do

```
{'b': var2 if var2 is not None else <some value>}
```

and what I want to do is have the `'b'` item excluded from the return dict completely.

There are various reasonably Pythonic ways to do this, but the ones I can think of all require you to iterate over a length-*n* iterable, where *n* is the number of arguments to `foo`:

```
# This works
def foo(var1, var2):
    mapping = [
        ('a', var1),
        ('b', var2),
    ]
    d = {k: v for (k, v) in mapping if v is not None}
    return d


# As does this
def foo(var1, var2):
    d = {
        'a': var1,
        'b': var2,
    }
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        if v is None:
            d.pop(k)
    return d
```

This isn't expensive but it'd be nice to be able to build the dict in one operation. **Can you build the dict in one operation?**

---

The motivation, if you're interested: `foo` actually calls a constructor `MyObj(**d)`, and this constructor can take a variable number of arguments. However, initializing `MyObj.b = None` is different from not initializing `MyObj.b`. And no, I can't alter `MyObj` :).

---

**Update:** Martijn Pieters' answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14263905/2452770) basically says you can't; you either have to process a separate iterable, or add the key afterwards (which generalizes to a loop over all arguments). If that's still the case I'm happy for this question to be closed.

Comment: You can't. But it looks like you already have a solution. Do you have a real question?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath edited to make question clearer

Comment: Couldn't you just do `d={}; if var2 is not None: d['b']` ?

Comment: Yes but I'd like this to generalize to more variables. Checking three or four like this seems pretty repetitive, and when you generalize that pattern you get one of the ones I showed above.