# Find all keys >= integer in Python dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, key

Say I have the following dictionary of epoch time keys:

```
dict = {
  "1363017884": "some val",
  "1363033813": "another val",
}
```

I would like to find all keys greater than say 1363033000 (in this case only 1363033813 would match).  I have a for loop that checks each key, but this seems so inefficient:

```
for epoch,value in dict.iteritems():
  if int(epoch) >= 1363033000:
    do something interesting
```

Comment: Be careful: you've redefined the ``dict`` built-in class in your example. Try to avoid using names like ``file``, ``dict``, ``list``, ``set``, otherwise you won't be able to use them as expected, later in your code.

Comment: @BalthazarRouberol In my code I am using a unique variable, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Absolutely, in this case it does not cause any problem, but it's just good practice.

Answer (score 7):

Looping over the dictionary is the only real choice you have, there is no more efficient method.

Or you could use a different data structure; storing integers connected to values in a btree structure for example would make searching for keys greater than or lower than a given search value much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could slightly modify the [code from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060972/subclassing-python-dictionary-to-override-setitem) to add a `large_keys` attribute. Now, whenever one of those large epochs gets added, the dict will keep track of them. When you want to iterate over them, you can simply iterate over that attribute.

```
class MyUpdateDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.large_keys = []
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        # optional processing here
        if int(key)>1363033000:
            self.large_keys.append((key,value))
        super(MyUpdateDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args:
            if len(args) > 1:
                raise TypeError("update expected at most 1 arguments, got %d" % len(args))
            other = dict(args[0])
            for key in other:
                self[key] = other[key]
        for key in kwargs:
            self[key] = kwargs[key]

    def setdefault(self, key, value=None):
        if key not in self:
            self[key] = value
        return self[key]
```

This might be overly simplistic, because the large value is hard-coded, but you can modify to make it a bit more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **numbers and strings as keys** in the dictionary first do that

```
myStringsList = [s for s in dictFromFile.keys() if s.isdigit()]
```

This will give you a list with the numbers as string.

Then convert the **string list to an int list** and **get only the > than X** elements:

```
myFinalList = [s for s in map(int, mynewlist) if s > X]
```

Hope it helps!