# python pretty print dictionary with multiline text in a value?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

here is a dict with `\n` in values:

```
d = {'trace': '\n\n##### Thread Stack Trace #####\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 525, in __bootstrap\n    self.__bootstrap_inner()\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner\n    self.run()\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run\n    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)\n  File "/usr/local/test_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test/plugin.py", line 303, in run_forever\n    self.process()\n  File "/usr/local/test_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test/common.py", line 170, in execute\n    return func(*args, **kwargs)\n  File "/usr/local/test_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test_plugin/system/schedule.py", line 153, in process\n    self.sleep(delta_ts)\n  File "/usr/local/test_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test/plugin.py", line 292, in sleep\n    self.cancelled.wait(interval)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 404, in wait\n    self.__cond.wait(timeout)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 263, in wait\n    _sleep(delay)\n'}
```

want to pretty print it, but when i try

```
In [47]: print d
{'trace': '\n\n##### Thread Stack Trace #####\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 525, in __bootstrap\n    self.__bootstrap_inner()\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner\n    self.run()\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run\n    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)\n  File "/usr/local/test_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test/plugin.py", line 303, in run_forever\n    self.process()\n  File "/usr/local/test_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test/common.py", line 170, in execute\n    return func(*args, **kwargs)\n  File "/usr/local/test_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test_plugin/system/schedule.py", line 153, in process\n    self.sleep(delta_ts)\n  File "/usr/local/test_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test/plugin.py", line 292, in sleep\n    self.cancelled.wait(interval)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 404, in wait\n    self.__cond.wait(timeout)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 263, in wait\n    _sleep(delay)\n'}

In [48]: import json

In [49]: print json.dumps(d, indent=4)
{
    "trace": "\n\n##### Thread Stack Trace #####\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py\", line 525, in __bootstrap\n    self.__bootstrap_inner()\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py\", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner\n    self.run()\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py\", line 505, in run\n    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/local/test_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test/plugin.py\", line 303, in run_forever\n    self.process()\n  File \"/usr/local/test_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test/common.py\", line 170, in execute\n    return func(*args, **kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/local/test_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test_plugin/system/schedule.py\", line 153, in process\n    self.sleep(delta_ts)\n  File \"/usr/local/test_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test/plugin.py\", line 292, in sleep\n    self.cancelled.wait(interval)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py\", line 404, in wait\n    self.__cond.wait(timeout)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py\", line 263, in wait\n    _sleep(delay)\n"
}


In [50]: from pprint import pprint

In [51]: pprint(d)
{'trace': '\n\n##### Thread Stack Trace #####\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 525, in __bootstrap\n    self.__bootstrap_inner()\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner\n    self.run()\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run\n    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)\n  File "/usr/local/test_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test/plugin.py", line 303, in run_forever\n    self.process()\n  File "/usr/local/test_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test/common.py", line 170, in execute\n    return func(*args, **kwargs)\n  File "/usr/local/test_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test_plugin/system/schedule.py", line 153, in process\n    self.sleep(delta_ts)\n  File "/usr/local/test_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test/plugin.py", line 292, in sleep\n    self.cancelled.wait(interval)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 404, in wait\n    self.__cond.wait(timeout)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 263, in wait\n    _sleep(delay)\n'}
```

all of the above do not work, how to pretty print it like this:

```
{u'trace': '''

##### Thread Stack Trace #####
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 525, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/test_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test/plugin.py", line 389, in run_forever
    self.sleep(wait_time)
  File "/usr/local/test_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test/plugin.py", line 292, in sleep
    self.cancelled.wait(interval)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 404, in wait
    self.__cond.wait(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 263, in wait
    _sleep(delay)

'''
}
```

Comment: Your pretty-print expected output is not valid Python or JSON syntax, which is what the other formats produce. You could show the output as a triple-quoted string, but I'm not aware of any *already available* function or library that can produce this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's not nested, you can do:

```
def my_pprint(d):
    print "{" + ",\n".join("{}: '{}'".format(repr(k), v) for k,v in d.items()) + "}"
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple two line code can do the work for you with your dict including \n in the value.

```
def print_dict(d):
    str= '{'
    for k,v in d.items():
        str+="\n\'{}\' : {}".format( k,v)
    str+= '}'
    print str
```

Another way to pretty print using the python builtin library pprint.

```
import pprint
print pprint.pformat(dict_object)
```

Other ways are to override the print method for the dict object.

These answers may help you out for this.

[How to "perfectly" override a dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387691/python-how-to-perfectly-override-a-dict)

[Subclassing Python dictionary to override __setitem__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060972/subclassing-python-dictionary-to-override-setitem)