# Suppose I want to implement an InsertOnlyDict, what's the best way to implement it?

Tags: python

I'm thinking how can we implement a `InsertOnlyDict`, which have the property that, if a key already exists, it can't be set to new value.

One way to implement it is to write something like:

```py
class InsertOnlyDict(dict):
  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    if key in self:
      raise ....
    super(InsertOnlyDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
```

The method above has the problem that, if caller uses `dict.__setitem__(x, k, v)`, it can still update this.

The second way to implement this is to write,

```py
class InsertOnlyDict(object):
  __slots__ = ('_internal',)
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self._internal = dict(*args, **kwargs):

  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    if key in self._internal:
      raise....
    self._internal[key] = value
```

The most concern of this approach is that, this `InsertOnlyDict` is no longer a `dict` and can hence fails checks like `isinstance(x, dict)`.

Is there any way to get around it? e.g. making a class not really using parent's class while still getting through checks like `isinstance(x, dict)`?

What do you think about these approaches?

Comment: No, if you want to use a dict, you have to accept that dicts are allowed to do things you don't want them to. In this case testing for `isinstance(x, dict)` would be incorrect, since if `x` is an instance of a dict, then dict methods would work on it

Comment: take a look of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060972/subclassing-python-dictionary-to-override-setitem)

Comment: You mention "The method above has the problem that, if caller uses dict.setitem(x, k, v), it can still update this". But that's Python's philosophy. You don't have to code a solution that blocks a programmer from purposedly achieve something. You've blocked involuntary re-assignments and I think that's just as far as you need to go...

Comment: you have to implement `update()` and `setdefault()` too

Comment: I think it's _very_ unlikely anyone would use `dict.__setitem__(x, k, v)` on it (which actually would need to be something like `dict.__setitem__(iod_object, x, k, v)`) — so would do it that way. Likewise for the other methods that are going to also need to be overridden.